# show image in webpage in android

Tags: android

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String html = "<H1>A simple HTML page</H1><body>" +"<a>link using anchor tag</a>"+

            "<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>";
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

after link, I want so show image. so
how to put address of that image if it is stored in `/images` folder of sdcard
i.e. what should be address in `src` attribute?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

Comment: pls dont forget to upvote an mark as accepted if it helped to you . http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: after few mins I'll b allowed..wait

Answer (score 0):

In a imagePath , set location of your image. Like here its showing test.jpg file is stored in images folder.

```
 String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
 String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/images/test.jpg";
 String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
  mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```